# Firefox: scrolling iframe that contains embed youtube video

Tags: firefox, iframe, youtube, scroll, mousewheel

**Scenario**

My page `p1` contains an iframe.
The iframe points to a page `p2` containing an embedded video from youtube.

**Problem**

The problem is that if I scroll (by mouse) the page inside the iframe, it scrolls normally only if the mouse cursor isn't on a youtube embdedded video.

But if the mouse cursor is on a youtube embedded video, the page `p2` inside the iframe stops to scroll, while the external page `p1` starts to scroll.

How can avoid this no normal behaviour?

I expect that even if the mouse cursor is on the youtube embedded video, the page inside the iframe continues to scroll normally, and it doesn't loose the mousewheel event.

**Failed solutions**

I tried to add the attribute `wmode="transparent"` to the iframe tag of youtube embedded video, but it doesn't solve the problem.

**Details**

To scroll inside the iframe I'm using a plugin that substitues the scrollbar.

**Demo**

You can find the demo [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/VHgjplC9o57b0rickPZt?p=preview). Open it with Firefox and scroll with the mouse inside the iframe

Comment: Well, that’s Flash for you – the beloved usability killer! And `wmode` is a parameter for the flash object itself, not for iframes.

Comment: I havent tried but couldnt you add a transparent div on top of the video to make the thing scrolling. This might lose the possibility to click on video playback buttons tho.

Comment: I added a plunker reproducing the problem

Comment: @KaarelKont-Kontson your solution works on Firefox, but not on Chrome. Specifically in Firefox I can click to play, in Chrome I cannot do it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution, got observing Facebook code.

Basically, instead of using iframe to embed youtube video, I'm using the `<embed>` tag, like the following code:

```
<embed  wmode="opaque" salign="tl" allowscriptaccess="never" allowfullscreen="true" scale="scale" quality="high" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" name="swf_u_jsonp_2_2b" id="swf_u_jsonp_2_2b" style="display: block;" src="https://www.youtube.com/v/XvLAKrVbCBM?version=3&autohide=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find a solution, other than that suggested by @Kaarel Kont-Kontson.
If I put a div in top of the video the user can play the video and can scroll even if the mouse cursor in on the video.

Specifically, the following is the div to display a single video:

```
<div style="position:relative; height:200px; width:200px;">
        <iframe style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;z-index:-10;" src="//youtube.com/embed/dooCQdg9-NA"></iframe>
        <div style="height:100%;width:100%;position:absolute;z-index:20;"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: One problem of this solution is that it works on Firefox, but in Chrome I cannot click on play to play the video.